# Uniqueness of Hartogs' extension theorem

Tags: general-topology, compactness, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}^n, n\geq 2$, and $K$ be a compact subset of $\Omega$
such that $\Omega\setminus K$ is connected.

From Hartogs' extension theorem, we know each holomorphic function over $\Omega\setminus K$  can be
extended to a holomorphic function over $\Omega$. Does this extension is unique?

Hence, we need an extra assumption that $\Omega$ is **connected** to assure  this extension is unique.

Is it **necessary**?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. If $\Omega \setminus K$ is connected, can $\Omega$ be not connected?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hartogs' extension is unique, we just need to prove the following:
**Theorem** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,n\geq 1$, $K$ be a compact subset of $\Omega$ and $\Omega\setminus K$ is connected, then $\Omega$ must be connected.
**Proof** If $\partial\Omega=\emptyset$, then $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected. Suppose $\partial\Omega\neq\emptyset$, and let $O_i, i\in I, |I|\geq 2$ be all connected components of $\Omega$, and
$$K_i=K\cap O_i, U_i=O_i\setminus K_i.$$
Clearly, $U_i$ is open in $\Omega\setminus K$, and
$$\Omega\setminus K=\cup_i U_i,\ U_i\cap U_j=\emptyset.$$
By the definition of connectedness, there must exist $j\in I$ such that
$U_i=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$, then $O_i\subset K, \forall i\neq j,$
which implies
$$0\leq d(K, \partial \Omega)\leq d(K,\partial O_i)=0, i\neq j,$$
contradicts with the fact that
$$d(K,\partial \Omega)>0.$$

**A counterexample:** The closed topologist's sine curve.